# Should I explicitly create a relation symmetrical to "Belongs To" or "Has Many"?

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I am new to ORM (and GORM) so apologies if this is an obvious question, but it does not seem to be covered by the documentation.

I will be using the [examples from the documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html) as a base to my questions

#### Question 1: Belongs To

```golang
// `User` belongs to `Company`, `CompanyID` is the foreign key
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company
}

type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}
```

- A `User` belongs to one `Company` only → this is handled by the code
  above
- A `Company` has many `User` → **is this implied by the code
  above?** Or should I add somehow a relation O2M in `Company`?

#### Question 2: Has Many

```golang
// User has many CreditCards, UserID is the foreign key
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  CreditCards []CreditCard
}

type CreditCard struct {
  gorm.Model
  Number string
  UserID uint
}
```

- A `User` has 1+ `CreditCard`→ this is handled by the code
- A `CreditCard` can belong to several users (say, a shared family CC) → **is it implied?** (if not: how to set up the O2M relationship).
  Or is it, instead, a case where a `CreditCard` is **explicitly configured** to belong to **only one** user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1:**  Based on how you defined your structs, you don't need an explicit O2M relationship in the `Company` struct, but when loading Company details, if you want to load all users that are assigned to that specific company, you need to add that field as well. It will need an additional function call like `Preload` or `Joins`, but you shouldn't need an explicit definition of this relationship.

```
type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
  Users []User
}
```

**Q2:** The way the relationship is defined now, it is configured so that a `CreditCard` belongs to only one user. If you want a many2many relationship, you need to specify the relation table. There is more documentation on it [here](https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#content-inner), but it should look something like this:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  CreditCards []CreditCard `gorm:"many2many:users_creditcards"`
}

type CreditCard struct {
  gorm.Model
  Number string
}
```

Comment: Than you. I am a bit confused by your answer for Q1. You say that no extra relationship is needed, but then provide in the code `Users []User`. I am not sure when this extra relationship is needed, and when not

Comment: As for Q2 - in retrospective this is obviously a M2M relationship (in my second point) - I was so focused on the relationship in the code that I missed the fact that "the inverse" one is the documented M2M. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For Q1, I was referring to the fact that you don't need additional annotations (like ``gorm:"some_expression"``). You need to add `Users []User` to the `Company` struct if you want to load all users that are assigned to that specific company.